# How to make a partition in Windows for a Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, partitioning

I've tried to find out how to do this without success. I want to make a partition that will be available for a Linux distribution to use when I install it, so I can set up a dual boot.

I have a single hard drive in my laptop which already has an unallocated space on it, but when I try to install my Linux distro it only recognises the main hard drive, and not the partitions within it.

I'm using Windows 8.1 How do I set up a partition that I can install Linux to?

Comment: Does your Linux distro have UEFI and/or GPT support?

Comment: Probably. but I have an old legacy version laptop anyway.

Answer (score 1):

***DO NOT USE THE STANDARD WINDOWS UTILITIES TO CREATE PARTITIONS TO WHICH YOU'LL INSTALL LINUX!!!!***

On a BIOS-based install (using an MBR disk), Windows' tools tend to convert a disk from a conventional setup to one that uses the [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) system, which is next to impossible to use for Linux installation. This is most likely to happen when you increase the number of partitions beyond 4. If this happens, you'll have to jump through some hoops to convert back from LDM to a regular setup. The risk of this happening is much lower on a newer GPT disk (used on EFI-based installations, which includes the vast majority of pre-installed Windows 8 and later systems), but even on such systems, your Linux install might need or want to use multiple partitions, so unless you know what you're doing, you really shouldn't be trying to set them up within Windows. Instead, leave it to the Linux partitioning tools that run as part of the Linux installation.

Given your symptom ("when I try to install my Linux distro it only recognises the main hard drive, and not the partitions within it"), I'd say that your partition table is damaged, or at least a little quirky. Linux's libparted tool, which is used by most Linux installation programs, tends to flake out when it sees the slightest problem, resulting in the disk appearing to be a unpartitioned. Preparing partitions in Windows *will not fix this problem,* so you'll end up with a risk of new problems and a 0% chance of proceeding further with your installation. Instead, I recommend you fix the problem. I describe the problem, and how to fix it, in more detail on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html) In brief, my [FixParts program](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/), which is part of the `gdisk` package in most Linux distributions, can probably fix the problem more-or-less automatically. In some cases, more manual repairs will be necessary, but it's impossible to provide specific advice without more information. I recommend you read the two pages linked to earlier in this paragraph and see what FixParts tells you about the disk. If you've got stray GPT data on an MBR disk or some other problem that FixParts can easily repair, use FixParts to deal with the issue. If that doesn't help, post back with more details, including the output of the following Linux commands:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda print
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

(These all assume that the disk in question is `/dev/sda`. If you've got multiple disks, it might need to be `/dev/sdb` or something else.) Edit your original question to add this information, adding four spaces to the start of each line of program output to help keep it legible. (Four spaces at the start of each line is a signal to this site to use a monospace font and not mess with formatting; otherwise this site will try to format the text as if it were an English paragraph, which reduces legibility of program output.)

Comment: Just to clarify @Rod Smith; do I run FixParts during the install of my Linux distro?

Comment: No; run it before you attempt to install Linux again. It should fix your partition table, thus permitting the installation to proceed.

Comment: Fixparts won't work for me. I try to run it as an administrator, and I follow the directions on your tutorial on RodsBooks, but it just throw out some text and then shuts down. It shuts down so fast that I can't even get a screenshot of the window, so I can't tell you what it says.

Comment: Try running it from a Linux emergency system (say, an Ubuntu installation disk in "try before installing" mode). Also, if Windows is shutting down when you run FixParts, then something is very wrong. This *might* be a hardware fault, such as bad sectors on the disk. Thus, you might want to run a SMART test on the disk, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Ok, I'll try running the Linux emergency system. Just to clarify though, it's not Windows that shuts down, just the Fixparts console.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RodSmith but after talking to the guy at my local computer repair and sales store I've decided to abandon the idea of a dual boot system. He says that he has people coming to him all the time that have problems with them, and I don't think I'm quite technical enough to maintain a system like that. Also, my laptop is too valuable - as I use it for work - to take a risk.

Answer (score 0):

Make Room for Linux: You’ll need free space on your Windows system drive to install Linux, or possibly a second entirely different hard drive if you have a desktop PC, resize your Windows system partition to make room for Linux, most Linux installers allow you to resize Windows NTFS partitions, so you can do this during the installation process, you can shrink your Windows system partition from within Windows itself to avoid any potential problems.

Open the Disk Management, press Windows Key + R, type diskmgmt.msc into the Run dialog, and press Enter. Right-click the Windows system partition — that’s likely your C:\ drive — and select “Shrink Volume.” Shrink it to free up space for your new Linux system. then you can install Linux.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already shrunk the drive. The problem is that the Linux distro I have doesn't recognise that there's partitions.

Comment: simly make unallocated space.